# Variáveis globais em GLSL?

Tags: opengl

Existe alguma maneira de declarar variáveis para que possam ser utilizadas em outros arquivos, com o mesmo valor da original? Já tentei usar o `varying` mas ela só funciona para o arquivo `.vsh` e `.fsh` da mesma parte. Exemplo:

No arquivo **composite.vsh**:

```
bool isNight = false;
void main() {
    isNight = true;
}
```

Ai, eu uso essa mesma variávei no arquivo **skybasic.vsh**:

```
if (isNight) {
    //está noite
}
```

sem ter que "recriar" tudo de novo essa variável. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Não sei ao certo o que você está querendo fazer. As variáveis do tipo `varying` servem para repassar dados do vertex shader para o fragment shader.

Existem as variáveis do tipo `attribute` que você envia os valores através da sua aplicação, então a partir do código da aplicação, você pode enviar para quantos shaders desejar.

Também existem as do tipo `uniform`, que são enviadas a partir da aplicação, a diferença em relação ao `attribute` é que as `uniform` não podem ser modificadas depois que estão no shader. Acho que seu caso seja as `uniform`